# Installed PyCharm and Anaconda, but Can't Enable Pandas and NumPy

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm, anaconda

I type in import pandas as pd and it returns ModuleNotFoundError. I opened PyCharm in a Conda environment, so I am very confused.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow please read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and do need full to this question and for all your next question

Answer (score 2):

If you installed anaconda, numpy and pandas are installed already.  You need to select your interpreter. See steps 5 and 6 [here](https://medium.com/@GalarnykMichael/setting-up-pycharm-with-anaconda-plus-installing-packages-windows-mac-db2b158bd8c) if you dont know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

[Press on it with the mouse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvWTR.jpg) Did you already try to click on the module and press Alt + Enter. There you can select "Install package"

Comment: Where would that be located in PyCharm?

Comment: You have to click on the package (import numpy) for example numpy and the press alt+enter then a menu appers where you can select install package numpy

Comment: import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/vinayakroy/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-P/ch-0/183.5153.39/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Comment: That is what I am currently receiving. Should I uninstall all forms of Python on my Macbook Pro? Including 2.x and Anaconda?

Comment: Did you press on numpy (in your code) and installed it?

Comment: I am new to programming, so I am not sure where you want me to click or how to install. I apologize for my lack of understanding, as I have just started

Comment: No problem, so you have can click on File in the top bar then you click on settings there you click on Project: [your projectname]  -> Project Interpreter then click on the plus symbol on the left. after that a new window should appear there you can search the package and select it on the right and press the button Install Package

Comment: Ok also another question is it ok to delete old Python 2.x files off my Mac

Comment: Do you use Python2 if you don´t you can delete them but take care that you don´t delte .py files that you´ve made

Answer (score 0):

Pycharm->File->Settings-> Project Interpreter ->click on settings icon-> add -> select system interpreter -> click on three dots -> find Anaconda3 ->Tools->python.exe-> apply/ok